# Google-Forms response with Python?

Tags: python, google-forms

I'm trying to write a Python-Script which makes it possible to submit responses in Google-Forms like this one:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/152CTd4VY9pRvLfeACOf6SmmtFAp1CL750Sx72Rh6HJ8/viewform

But how to I actually send the POST and how can I find out, what this POST should actually contain?

Answer (score 24):

First `pip install requests`

You have to post some specific form data to a specific url,you can use requests.The form_data dict params are correspondent to options,if you don't need some options,just remove it from form_data.

```
import requests
url = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/152CTd4VY9pRvLfeACOf6SmmtFAp1CL750Sx72Rh6HJ8/formResponse'
form_data = {'entry.2020959411':'18+ sollte absolute Pflicht sein',
            'entry.2020959411':'Alter sollte garkeine Rolle spielen',
            'entry.2020959411':'17+ wäre für mich vertretbar',
            'entry.2020959411':'16+ wäre für mich vertretbar',
            'entry.2020959411':'15+ wäre für mich vertretbar',
            'entry.2020959411':'Ausnahmen von der Regel - Dafür?',
            'entry.2020959411':'Ausnahmen von der Regel - Dagegen?',
            'entry.2020959411':'__other_option__',
            'entry.2020959411.other_option_response':'test',
            'draftResponse':[],
            'pageHistory':0}
user_agent = {'Referer':'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/152CTd4VY9pRvLfeACOf6SmmtFAp1CL750Sx72Rh6HJ8/viewform','User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36"}
r = requests.post(url, data=form_data, headers=user_agent)
```

Comment: How to do post if there is an "upload file" field in the form?

Answer (score 6):

Based on the answer from @pigletfly I wrote a little script for harvesting the field names (for a text-field only form)

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, warnings
def get_questions(in_url):
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(in_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.read(), 'html.parser')
    get_names = lambda f: [v for k,v in f.attrs.items() if 'label' in k]
    get_name = lambda f: get_names(f)[0] if len(get_names(f))>0 else 'unknown'
    all_questions = soup.form.findChildren(attrs={'name': lambda x: x and x.startswith('entry.')})
    return {get_name(q): q['name'] for q in all_questions}
def submit_response(form_url, cur_questions, verbose=False, **answers):
    submit_url = form_url.replace('/viewform', '/formResponse')
    form_data = {'draftResponse':[],
                'pageHistory':0}
    for v in cur_questions.values():
        form_data[v] = ''
    for k, v in answers.items():
        if k in cur_questions:
            form_data[cur_questions[k]] = v
        else:
            warnings.warn('Unknown Question: {}'.format(k), RuntimeWarning)
    if verbose:
        print(form_data)
    user_agent = {'Referer':form_url,
                  'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36"}
    return requests.post(submit_url, data=form_data, headers=user_agent)
```

You can then use the get_questions function to get the fields which you can fill in

```
TEST_FORM_URL = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfBmvqCVeDA7IZP2_mw_HZ0OTgDk2a0JN4VlY5KScECWC-_yw/viewform"

anno_questions = get_questions(TEST_FORM_URL)
```

To get the questions (fields) as a dict

```
{'annotator': 'entry.756364489',
 'task': 'entry.1368373366',
 'item_id': 'entry.84713541',
 'label': 'entry.2072511216',
 'session': 'entry.2021127767',
 'time': 'entry.1122475936'}
```

then use the submit_response with keyword arguments to submit

```
submit_response(TEST_FORM_URL, anno_questions, annotator="TestUser", item_id = 0)
```

Comment: it is not extracing email question

Comment: getting response status code=401

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) and [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) to send the post.

Do something like this:

```
import urllib2, urllib
import cookielib

cookieJar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(
    urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cookieJar), # Create Opener
    urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
    urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0))

# Add Headers                    
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36")]


forms = {
             "formname": value,  # The forms name and the selected value you want
             "formname2": value2,
        }

data = urllib.urlencode(forms) # Encode data
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com',data) # Send Request
res = opener.open(req) # Open Request
html = res.read() # Read Response
```

you should structure it a bit like that.

To get the form names you need to look at the source code of the site and find the names of the forms you want to enter into and submit.

Hope this Helps

Good Luck:)

Comment: self is not defined

Comment: @TSR Oops! Just get rid of self! I must have taken the code out of a class I wrote and forgot to take off the self!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my script which works:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)'
header={'User-Agent' : user_agent}
url = "http://....Your google form"
# values from your form. You will need to include any hidden variables if you want to..
values= {
'entry.asdfsdfsdasd': 'asdfasdfsd',
'draftResponse':'[,,&quot;-asdfasdasdf&quot;]',
'pageHistory':'0',
'fbzx':'-asdfasdfsd'
}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
urllib2.Request(url, data, header)
```